# NoClassDefFoundError in android without external jars

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I only started on the android application today so I haven't added any jars. I am currently using sdk and adt r19 if it helps. 
How the android manifest looks like

```
    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UserHome"></activity>
</application>
```

How it happened:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
 public void onClick(View arg0){
      Intent mapIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserHome.class);
      LoginActivity.this.startActivity(mapIntent);
      Log.i("Intent", "Login to UserHome");
   }
});
```

I am clueless to why this is happening.

**Edit**

Error log

```
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.srd.application.UserHome
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.srd.application.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:70)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:4121)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:4431)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1061)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3740)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1667) 
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1102)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2063)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-13 06:14:06.844: E/AndroidRuntime(442):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What class exactly it can't find?

Comment: @Egor the UserHome class. Currently posting the error produced by logcat

Comment: write startActivity(mapIntent); instead of LoginActivity.this.startActivity(mapIntent);

Comment: @pierr posted error logs

Comment: And you're sure that UserHome is there and it's an Activity child?

Comment: Did you define UserHome as an `Activity` in your Manifest?

Comment: @Egor UserHome extends MapActivity

Comment: Did you build your project using Google APIs SDK and did you include Google Maps library in your manifest file?

Comment: @pierr I'm not sure about the ADT but Android SDK Manager tells me that I'm using SDK revision 19

Comment: @Egor Yes I did. Referred to this link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html

Comment: What API version are you building against?

Comment: @Egor API 8(Android 2.2)

Comment: It should be Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 8)

Comment: @Egor Sorry my mistake its Google apis. only saw api 8. There's the google libraries

Comment: @consprice try to write startActivity(mapIntent); instead of LoginActivity.this.startActivity(mapIntent);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you defined **use-library** tag in your application's manifest file?

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

like,

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    .
    .
     .
</application>
```

Also check for your application contains `Google-api` not `Android`.

Comment: still failed...I'm relaunching the emulator to see if it helps, yours should be the right answer